# What statistical test to use for two quantitative IVs over time?

Tags: regression, correlation, count-data

I am analyzing the correlation between average gust wind speeds from 1979 to present to deer pellet counts in a nearby refuge. I am not sure what statistical tests to use to analyze the correlation between these two variables besides linear regression and pearson's correlation. Would the tests for Constant Error Variance be applicable? and are there any other tests and online tools that I may use?

Pictures of the data tables I have:[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I added pictures of the data

Comment: Note that the bottom part of the image shows 11 different years, but only  four different gust speeds. Since the gust speeds are presented as accurate to three decimal places, so many identical values seems statistically suspicious to me.

Comment: @JamesPhillips the database (weather underground) which we got our data from had these as averages